# Image crop help using multiple imageview

Tags: android, crop

here's my problem... Would it be possible to load a picture, call the crop activity, and load the cropped images on different imageviews without changing the main image??
I have 3 imageviews. My imageview 1 is for the main image loadout, my imageview 2 is for the result of the crop activity, the same goes with imageview 3.

I am using com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0....

The good thing about this one is that it already has lots of functions, but the problem is that what I want to happen is that it would load the image that I have already called in my main imageview.

Comment: (Cant upload photo yet due to small reputation)

What I want to happen is when I click on my main imageview(the biggest), it would ask me to select an image in my gallery. When I press on the imageview 2(bottom left), it will invoke the crop method loading the image in the main imageview and storing the result of the cropped image in the imageview 2. Same goes with imageview 3(bottom right).

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the instances of the Views in the activity class.
2. Use the method below to get the image source to bitmap
3. Display bm returned from convertImageViewToBitmap to the second ImageView.

private Bitmap convertImageViewToBitmap(ImageView v){ 
        Bitmap bm = 
        ((BitmapDrawable)v.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
         return bm;
    }